# Запуск проекта на go на сервере

Tags: linux, ubuntu, golang

Всем  привет,  столкнулся из  следующей  проблемой.  Вообщем  есть  проект  на  go сервер убунту и  второй пк на  виндовс. Эти  2 компьютера  находятся в  одной локальной сети.  Я  запустил  проект на  сервере,  он  работет,  но, чтоб  мне  добраться к рабочему  проекту  через  браузер,  я  ввожу айпи пк,  а как  можно  написать  свое доменное имя? Пробовал  в  /etc/hosts писать  ip pc и  через  пробел  домен,  но  он  так не  работает,  как  можно  это решить?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял и вы хотите на своём компьютере писать доменное имя и попасть на удалённый сервер, то надо на компьютере с которого входите в файл *hosts* прописать соответствие ip и имени
Например если сервер имеет ip *192.168.0.1* ,а ваш Windows компьютер *192.168.0.2* и вы хотите с Windows заходить по имени myserver , то открываем файл  *C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts*
и добавляем в него следующую запись

```
192.168.0.1 myserver
```